# How Scroll RecyclerView With MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar, autoscroll

I have recyclerview in activity and mediaplayer. I want when play mediaplayer and when seekbar change position my recycleview scroll with him.befor i do for scrollbar and rigth work.but i can not do for recycler .
Please help me!?

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_matn);


public static void setAdapterLyric(List<Matn> matn) {
    adapterLyrics = new AdapterLyrics(matn);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterLyrics);
  }
```

and this my seekbar:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
          G.mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }
    });
```

Comment: there is no `RecyclerView` related part in your code

Comment: recycler added in my question

Comment: so how do you want to `"Scroll RecyclerView With MediaPlayer"` ?

Comment: i want for example when seekbar in 50% or mediplayer.getCurrenDuration() , recycler scroll(0,100) to 50% of height

Comment: so did you try any `RecyclerView#scroll*()` (or `LayoutManager#scroll*()` methods)?

Comment: no if you can and know help please

Comment: then do that, try them out